# Android start another Activity when onDestroy();

Tags: android, ondestroy, android-ondestroy

I need to destroy the activity `HomeActivity`  `onDestroy();` and then when enter to the app start the activity `SplashActivity` like a new `Intent`. Any idea to do it clear?

Comment: May be this can help , not sure though . Try : `onResume() {  // Start SplashActivty here }`  add this in HomeActivity .

Comment: @Vikrant The problem is that I only want to start the Splash when the activity HomeActivity pass for onDestroy. Is it clear to use a boolean to check if this happend? I need to do is to prevent GPU problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onDestroy()` is only called when you call `finish()` on your activity or the system is temporary destroying the system. So since you're not calling finish() on your activity, the `onDestroy()` will not be invoked. The workaround for this is, launching the splashscreen activity in your `onstop()` method. Like this

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class))

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Intent with flag - clear history

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove old activity from activity stack, start new activity using these intent flags

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

> It will clear activity stack and you new activity will be the *only*
>   activity in the stack.